# Complex commands with arguments in Power Shell Set-Alias

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I'm trying to use Power Shell 'Set-Alias' command to make an alias to a complex command with arguments. It doesn't work for anything but simple single commands (for which no alias is needed!). E.g., an alias to 'ls' works, but even one to 'ls *' does not.

PS C:\Users\snyde\BFROOT> Set-Alias

cmdlet Set-Alias at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: tdir
Value: ls *
PS C:\Users\snyde\BFROOT> tdir
tdir : The term 'ls *' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- tdir
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ls *:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\snyde\BFROOT> Set-Alias

cmdlet Set-Alias at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: tdir
Value: ls *
PS C:\Users\snyde\BFROOT> tdir
tdir : The term 'ls *' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- tdir
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ls *:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I expect 'tt' to execute 'ls *'

Comment: Have you tried passing -Option * when setting the alias? I don't use PowerShell much, but I think I've done that in the past.

Comment: Instead of an alias you should create a function. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Not supported, you need to define a function instead

Comment: In short: Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, you _cannot include pass-through arguments_ in a PowerShell alias definition - you need a _function_ for that. PowerShell aliases are simply _alternative names_ for other commands, with no ability to "bake in" arguments. E.g., to define a short command `bar` that invokes command `foo` with fixed argument `baz` while passing all other arguments through, use `function bar { foo baz @args }`